# What's use of header part of JWT token?

Tags: security, web, jwt, json-web-token

What's the use of header part of JWT(https://jwt.io) ? I found that if you removed that header part of it? It doesn't lose its security.

If JWT contains only two part, payload and signature: `yyyy.zzzz` instead of `xxxx.yyyy.zzzz`. You can still use the algorithm to check if `yyyy` matches `zzzz` after hashing.

Answer (score 2):

The header describe the cryptographic operations applied to the JWT: encryption (JWE) or signature/mac (JWS), and also could contain some additional properties like content type (`cty`)

The `typ` parameter will typically not be used by applications when it is already known that the object is a JWT. It is useful to disambiguate when the application can receive data structures that can contain JWTs

```
{"typ":"JWT",
  "alg":"HS256"}
```

The `alg` parameter describe the algorithm used to digitally sign/MAC the JWT, and  `enc` contains the encryption algorithm (if used JWE). This parameters can be used for JWT implementations to decode and verify the token property, but if the usage context is fixes may be ignored.